# Getting "invalid syntax" from previously working code

Tags: python, syntax-error

So I have the following code:

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')

text = f.read()

data = text.split()
print data


print '<HTML>\n    <HEAD>\n    </HEAD>\n    <BODY>\n        <table border="1">\n'
for x in data:
    print '            <tr>' + x + '<tr>'
print'</table>\n    </BODY>\n</HTML>'
```

before I tried to installed iPython, it was working with the default Python shell.
But after I installed distribute and pyreadline and then iPhython, the code won't stop giving me syntax errors, as if not a single variable would work, not sure if there is something about python initialization/declaration that I have missed or if something went wrong with doing stuff on the console, but it certainly is driving me crazy and I need to fix it.

P.S. I use Windows 8

Edit:
Was asked for the errors I get, here are screenshots, since I do not get any very specific text-like errors.

[image]
In this second one, I edited the code several times to test different things,
hence why I get error for different variables.
Even the simplest of things would give me an error.
P.S.2. I just tried `print 'hey'` and it gave me the same error, not recognizing the `'` token.

[image]

Comment: Would help if you included the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like whatever you installed is using Python 3.x, and your code was written for Python 2.x.

In Python 3.x, `print` is now a function, not a keyword, so you'll have to change all the lines like...

```
print data
```

...to...

```
print(data)
```

If you need to retain Python 2.x compatibility, add the line...

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

...at the top of the code.

Comment: thank you so much, it was fixed. I cannot import due to project restrictions, but I will adhere to python 3.3's new syntax.